# how to compute value of intersection of two arrays?

Tags: c++, intersection

I was able to write a function that prints out the intersection of two arrays. However, I am trying to obtain the value of the members of the intersection.

If our final intersection is `{6, 12}` I should return 2 as the value because I have 2 members. My return value is 1 and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
int main()
{
    int data1[] = { 3, 6, 9, 12};
    int data2[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 };
    int result[] = {};
    size_t length1 = sizeof(data1)/sizeof(int);
    size_t length2 = sizeof(data2)/sizeof(int);
    size_t resultMax= 0;
    int i =0;
    int j =0;

    while (i < length1 && j < length2)
    {
        if (data1[i] < data2[j])
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if (data2[j] < data1[i])
        {
            j++;
        }
        else if (data1[i] == data2[j])
        {
            result[i] = data1[i];
            cout << "valor : " << result[i] << endl; // output is 6 and 12
            i++;
            j++;
            resultMax = sizeof(result[i])/sizeof(int);
        }
    }

    cout << "Final Size: "<< resultMax; //output is 0
    return resultMax;
}
```

Comment: `result` is an empty array.  You can't write _anything_ to it.  What you're doing results in Undefined Behavior, and will clobber other variables or stack data.

Comment: i’m not c++ expert so maybe there’s a syntax thing i’m missing but you’re doing `sizeof(result[i].....)` which is just one element which of course if you divide it by the size of an `int` will be 1... done you just want `sizeof(result...)` ...?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm how do I copy whatever value stores data1[I] to my result array. and then return the length of that array?

Comment: @mad.meesh I don't know how to get the length of my final array.. :S

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: `I don't know what I am doing wrong` you are not debugging your code

Answer (score 1):

Use [**std::vector**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of array.

```
# include<iostream>
# include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> data1 = { 3, 6, 9, 12}, data2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 }, result;
    int i = 0, j = 0, length1 = data1.size(), length2 = data2.size();
    while (i < length1 && j < length2)
    {
        if (data1[i] < data2[j])
            i++;
        else if (data2[j] < data1[i])
            j++;
        else if (data1[i] == data2[j])
        {
            result.push_back(data1[i]);
            cout << "valor : " << data1[i] << endl;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Final Size: "<< result.size(); 
    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Code**](https://ideone.com/lfWabD)

Answer (score 1):

Use the algorithm library, specifically [std::set_intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

The following is a slightly adapted example from the above linked cppreference page:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{3, 6, 9, 12};
    std::vector<int> v2{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 };
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    std::vector<int> v_intersection;

    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v_intersection));

    std::cout << "Final Size: "<< v_intersection.size();
}
```